# Ruby program to count the number of times the value appears among all the values in the hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I am trying to write a ruby program to count the number of times the value appears among all the values in the hash. For that, I am creating a method -

> count_value(hash, value)

```html
def count_value(hash, value)
    Hash[hash.group_by { |k, value| value }.map { |k, value| [k, value.count] }]
end

puts count_value(hash, 2)
```

But, I am not getting the actual result. I want result in this format :-

```
count_value(hash, 2) => 1
count_value(hash, 3) => 1
count_value(hash, 5) => 2
count_value(hash, 10) => 0
```

How to achieve this? What is the mistake I have done in the code snippet?

Comment: Your method takes a `hash` argument. But you're shadowing it by reassigning it in the first line of the method (`hash = {a: 5, b:2, c: 3, d: 5}`).

Comment: `hash.values.count {|v| v == value}`. It doesn't help that you're calling everything "value" though; this makes the code a little harder to understand ;)

Comment: @max - If I remove that hash argument, then i get result like this - {5=>2, 2=>1, 3=>1} . which is not matching with the testcases.

Comment: @avidCoder By the way, your code **ALMOST** works, but you've over-engineered it: You're calculating the tally of all values, rather than just counting occurrences of one value.  You could get from your current result to the desired result by slapping `[value]` on the end.

Comment: Also, there's a clever little way you could have solved this harder problem of "building a tally of occurrences..." - ruby has a special method called `tally` :) You could have done this: `hash.values.tally`. Then to get to your desired result, use `hash.values.tally[value] || 0`

Comment: Please post some sample inputs and expected outputs. Otherwise, you leave people guessing about the shape of your input hashes, which wastes everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

```
h = {a: 5, b:2, c: 3, d: 5}
value_to_be_counted = 5

p h.count{|k, v| v == value_to_be_counted  }  # => 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
def get_hash_dup_count(hash_data)
    arr_elem_count = Hash.new(0)
    hash_values = hash_data.values
    puts "Hash values are : #{hash_values}"
    hash_values.each do |v|
          arr_elem_count[v] += 1
    end
    return arr_elem_count
end

def count_value(hash_data, value)
    arr_val_count = get_hash_dup_count(hash_data)
    puts arr_val_count[value]
end

hash_data = {
    "x" => 1,
    "y" => 2,
    "z" => 1,
    "k" => 0
  }

count_value(hash_data, 2)
```